# Why my code is returning Promise { <pending> }

Tags: mysql, node.js

I guys, new to node and trying to figure out what I am doing wrong with these promises, I decided to copy the full code of my route to help a full understandment and hopefully some help, thank you!

```
router.get('/mygroups', function (req, res, next) {

    const db = require('../db.js');

    let grouplist = [];
    var groupcards = '';
    var imgreturned = '';

    var dbgroupreturn = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        db.query('SELECT id, Group_name, Group_Activity, Group_Photo, Group_Creator, Group_members FROM groups ', function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;

            const UserID = (req.user.user_id);

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var memberlist = results[i].Group_members;

                for (var j = 0; j < memberlist.length; j++) {
                    if (memberlist[j] == UserID) {
                        grouplist.push(results[i]);

                    }

                }
            }

            resolve(grouplist);
        })
    }).then(function (grouplist) {
        for (var k = 0; k < grouplist.length; k++) {
            var groupname = "<a href='group?" + grouplist[k].id + "'><div class='groupcarddiv'><h3>" + grouplist[k].Group_name + "</h3>";
            var groupActivity = "<p>" + grouplist[k].Group_Activity + "</p>";
            var groupPhoto = "<p>" + grouplist[k].Group_Photo + "</p>";
            var groupCreator = "<p>" + grouplist[k].Group_Creator + "</p>";

            var groupmemberlist = JSON.parse(grouplist[k].Group_members);

            async function findpicture(id) {
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    db.query('SELECT User_Profile_Photo FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id], function (error, results, fields) {
                        if (error) {
                            throw error;
                        } else {
                            imgname = results[0].User_Profile_Photo;
                            resolve(imgname);
                        }
                    });
                });
                return imgreturned
            };

            for (var m = 0; m < groupmemberlist.length; m++) {
                var imgtag = await findpicture(groupmemberlist[m]);
                var imgtagresolved = imgtag.then(function (imgname) {

                    var imgreturned = '<img href="/uploads/' + imgname + ">";
                    return imgreturned;

                })
                console.log(imgtagresolved);
                // intention is to define groupMembers = as a div with the img tags inside, I am letting the console.log above to show results I am getting before be sure I can use the promise value into this var
            }



            var groupMembers = "<p>" + grouplist[k] + "</p></div></a>";
            groupcards += groupname + groupActivity + groupPhoto + groupCreator + groupMembers;
        }

        res.render('mygroups', {
            title: 'Groups',
            showgroups: groupcards,
        });
    })
})
```

I am getting the return Promise {  } from the console.log I am using on line 39, I am trying to understand the concept of promises and it has taken me 3 days and my mood to understand how to retrive the value into the variable only after it has being filled, thank you!

Comment: Promises are a part of asynchronous programming. In asynchronous programming you cannot rely on a certain state of a program at a certain line in the program, ever. There is no way* to make any method wait for a Promise to be fulfilled. The only tihng you can rely on si that the promise WILL be fulfilled (that's why it is called a promise). So isntead of halting program flow until it is fulfilled, you use callbacks that run once it is.

Comment: (* = there is A way that makes use of `yield` and callbacks, but it defeats the entire purpose of Promises and is also neither flexible nor elegant)

Comment: It's not clear to me what your specific question is.  We can't explain the generic concept of promises and how to use them here.  We could answer a very specific question about your code (if you asked a clear one).

Comment: I want to understand why console.log( imgreturned) is returning {<pending>} instead return the values of if since I am using await and calling it after use .then on the previous variable

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about this line of code:

```
console.log(imgtagresolved);
```

Then, that should indeed be a promise in the pending state.  That variable comes from this:

```
var imgtagresolved = imgtag.then(function (imgname) {...});
```

And, `imgtag.then()` returns a promise - always.  So, your code is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.  `imgtagresolved` is a promise just like it's supposed to be.  That's how the `.then()` method works.

You get the value from a promise in one of two ways:

1. Using `p.then(val => { /* access val in here */})` on the promise.
2. Using `let val = await p;` on the promise when inside an `async` tagged function.

That's how you get data from a promise.

---

Your code appears to contain a lot of problems and misunderstandings of how asynchronous code and promises work.  This place isn't really for rewriting a whole large block of code for you and we could even do so if we wanted to because there's no description of what you're really trying to accomplish.  So, it's not clear how we can help any more specifically.